Flutter riverpod state notifier not updating the ui
I'm using StateNotifier for login/logout. The screen doesn't change when I log in, but it works fine after hot reload or logout. Auth state is updated, but the UI doesn't refresh.
I'm using StateNotifier for login/logout. The screen doesn't change when I log in, but it works fine after hot reload or logout. Auth state is updated, but the UI doesn't refresh.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: false,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(
          Theme.of(context).textTheme,
        ),
        // primarySwatch: AppColors.sdColor1,
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
        indicatorColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
      home: Consumer(
        builder: (context, ref, child) {
          ref.listen<bool>(
            isLoadingProvider,
            (_, isLoading) {
              if (isLoading) {
                LoadingScreen.instance().show(
                  context: context,
                );
              } else {
                LoadingScreen.instance().hide();
              }
            },
          );
          final isloggedIn = ref.watch(isLoggedInProvider);
          print("Islogged in is $isloggedIn");
          if (isloggedIn) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text("Welcome"),
              ),
              body: Center(
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await ref.read(authStateProvider.notifier).logout();
                    },
                    child: const Text("Log Out")),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return const OnboardingScreen();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

`
i checked all the code i did not found any bug

I think the solution should be something like this (more or less):
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:functional_widget_annotation/functional_widget_annotation.dart';


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {    
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: false,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(
      Theme.of(context).textTheme,
    ),
    // primarySwatch: AppColors.sdColor1,
  ),
  darkTheme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
    indicatorColor: Colors.blueGrey,
  ),
  themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
  home: MyWidget(),
);
  }
}

// The Widget file:
@cwidget
Widget _myWidget(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {


return switch (ref.watch(isLoggedInProvider)) {
  AsyncData(:final value) => _buildWithData(context, value),
  AsyncError(:final error) => _buildWithError(....),
  _ => const Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ),
    };
  } 


Widget _buildWithData(context, value) { 
  
      if (value.isLoggedIn) {
        return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Welcome"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              await ref.read(authStateProvider.notifier).logout();
            },
            child: const Text("Log Out")),
      ),
    );
  } else {
    return const OnboardingScreen();
  }
    },
  );
}

